# How to strip all non numeric characters including decimals from a javascript value

Tags: javascript

I've tried stripping out the decimal from this value, but it's not working

Here's what i have

```
<input type="number" class="blah" id="myID" name="amount" value="0.07" step="0.01" min="0.02" max="99999.99">

function () {
 return document.getElementById("myID").value = newVal.replace(/[^0-9|-]/g, "");
}
```

Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/sxmmsacx/

Comment: `.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementById("myID").value, 10)`?

Comment: Well the obvious is that `newVal` is undefined.

Comment: Is the output from `0.07` supposed to be `007` or `0`? Is the `|-` part of your regex trying to keep a leading `-` for negative numbers?

Comment: input type number accepts a valid number. If u need only Integer value have the step value set to 1. It's not clear why you are stripping the decimal point if your step value is 0.1

Comment: This is going to be an google analytics event value, it will not accept the decimal. It's going to represent $0.07 but I cant have any non int characters in the value

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your regular expression. You should have used + to signify 1 or more non numbers.

`newVal.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");`

Comment: @affiliatex - The JS code in your fiddle doesn't do anything because it has an error unrelated to the regex: it is trying to use an undefined variable. Check your browser's dev console.

Comment: @affiliatex Your code was horribly wrong. [Here's something working](https://jsfiddle.net/sxmmsacx/3/)

Comment: @AndrewL. yes i'm new to javascript - Thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

try using the code below

```
newVal.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: what's the expected output for that?

Comment: return document.getElementById("myID").value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");

Comment: it returns 0.07  I need it to return 007